# Is it possible to have vertically responsive features in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 panel lay out like this:
[image]

I want Pane 3 to disappear when the page height is less than some threshold.

Bootstrap's repsonsive features are triggered based on screen width.
As long as the screen is wide, bootstrap will not transition from lg to md to sm to xs. So on a wide but short screen, it would show all three panes. Given the content I want to show in Pane 2 and Pane 3, they can't be very short.

Is it possible to solve this using bootstrap or maybe some custom CSS that sits alongside bootstrap? As far as possible, wan't to avoid custom java script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), there is also `min-height`/`max-height`.

So you just do

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    .panel {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Many don't realize that height-based media queries also offer us a great deal of control. +1. And here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/x4p3oh3j/1/ .

Comment: And also, instead of W3Schools you may want to provide a more reliable reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to solve this using bootstrap

No. Bootstrap's grid system is column orientated and so 'horzontally minded', the responsiveness comes down to media queries which react to [**device screen width**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

> ...maybe some custom CSS that sits alongside bootstrap

Absolutely! In the same way Bootstrap uses [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to adjust CSS based on screen widths, you can use one to adjust CSS based on [`device-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-height) or [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#height) (both of which accept min and max prefixes).

> (device height) Describes the height of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document
>   window)

```css
/* Replace 500px with the height you wish to hide your block at, */

@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
  /* Instead of changing the body, you would add CSS to set display:none on the block in question*/
}
```